# Make warn_unused_result applied to all function with GCC

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, compiler-warnings

Is it possible to tell GCC to use **warn_unused_result** flag for all function even not having  the corresponding attribute? Because if I can forget to check for return value, I can also forget to add the GCC specific attribute.

I've seen it to be possible with some other compilers.

Comment: From reviewing the documentation I would say the answer is no.

Comment: alternative: you can run your programs through splint, testing for ignored return values: http://www.splint.org

Comment: Which compilers support it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can only tell gcc to ignore all `warn_unused_result` flags with `-Wno-unused-result` but the respective `-Wunused-result` only sets the default (to warn only on flags). Compiling with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` should have triggered a warning if it can be activated but it doesn't, so it cannot.

Besides that, I wonder why you would want this, it is not that uncommon to ignore the result of functions, and all libraries are likely to produce tons of warnings.

Comment: We are writing our own library and we want to exclude as much errors as possible. Several days ago I've noticed that one of our programmer did not checked result of __fread__. Indeed, such case is quite rare, but if it happens due to low resources on embedded machine, our lib have to handle it without crashing master app. So, we want to follow as many checks as possible.

Comment: @PoltoS: If you were using C++ there could be a way to wrap return types, but that would more or less work like `warn_unused_result`.

Comment: We are using C...  Strange that GCC does not provide such a flag. May be it is possible to hack it a bit to "virtually" add such a flag to each function?

Comment: @PoltoS: Well, if you want to go into the source code of gcc, sure, anything is possible. But other than that, I don't see an option.

Comment: I'm having the same issue and stumbled on this thread. Just a note on the fact that "all libraries are likely to produce tons of warnings": true, but one can turn off warnings from included libraries (with -isystem), so to have warnings only for the code he/she is developing...

It kind of sucks that this option is not in gcc...

Answer (score 0):

While it does not seem possible with GCC, you can run static analyzers like coverity and lint to catch these.

Comment: Nice answer after almost 5 years ;)

coverty is an SAAS. I can not upload company's code to some third party server. In addition third part server do know nothing about my environment and system include files. I've not found good static analysers so far that don't complain on platform specific types.

Comment: I'm not sure if coverity is a SaaS only offering. My employer uses coverity and I believe that no code leaves the organization's servers.

https://community.synopsys.com/s/question/0D53400003RpaYWCAZ/can-coverity-connect-be-installed-in-an-isolated-environment

Answer (score 0):

There is a clang plugin, in [elfs-clang-plugins](https://github.com/sinelaw/elfs-clang-plugins) (authored by myself, open source) that helps.

While not for GCC, it can still be useful e.g. if you can add it to your CI gatekeeping process (if you have one) or just run it manually once in a while.

The warn_unused_result plugin will emit a warning for functions that **lack a warn_unused_result attribute.** The plugin only considers functions declared or defined in the current compilation unit, so external libraries don't add noise.

The plugin accepts an optional arg, --static-only which causes it to warn only about static functions (for when changing external APIs is too much work).

Example:

```
int foo(void);
```

Compiler output:

```
/tmp/test.c:1:5: warning: missing attribute warn_unused_result
int foo(void);
```

Comment: @Machta - It should, but you should try.

Answer (score 0):

When using objc, you could suppress `warn_unused_result` warning like this,

```c
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-result"
    [YPKWhatsNewContainerViewModel checkWhatsNew]; // return value should be ignored
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```