# Neither -Wunused-result, nor --warn-unused-result generates warnings about unused results

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-warnings, gcc-warning

This (simplest-example) program is set up so `main()` calls the `makeKey()` function and fails to check the return value ...Which demonstrates why, when programming, especially security critical code [I'm looking at you Sony], it is important to check your return values.

```
[demo.c]
int makeKey (void) {  /* returns 0/false if there is an error */
    /* //! todo - just return an error for now [fred@sony] */
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    makeKey();  /* make a new key for the crypto */
    return 0;   /* return 0=success              */
}
```

I want my compiler (`gcc version 12.2.0`) to "complain" with a warning/error message such as: "return value not used"

It doesn't seem to matter what switches I add to `gcc`, it seems happy to ignore this easily-detected mistake ...After reading maaany articles, I've got this far:

```
gcc -Werror -Wall -Wextra -Wunused-result --warn-unused-result -pedantic-errors -ansi -std=c99 demo.c
```

...But still no luck!

I have discovered that I can make each function "opt-in" to this sanity/security check with:

```
int makeKey (void) __attribute__ ((warn_unused_result)) {  // returns 0 if there is an error
```

But I want the security to be enabled by default (with an attribute that allows you to "opt-out", eg. `printf()`)

- Is this even possible with a standard install of `gcc v12`?
- If so, what command line switch am I missing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13334324/make-warn-unused-result-applied-to-all-function-with-gcc - Nothing seems to have changed in 11.5 years

Comment: Oh wow! I missed that post on my quest! ...I shall remain hopeful that this updated version catches the eye of some guru who knows of some new, poorly-documented feature :)

Comment: Since C23, you can use `[[nodiscard]]` instead of the gcc extension. Slightly less typing anyway :-)

Comment: GCC aims at general purpose use, where such warnings will generate a lot of noise. I suspect fear of that hinders the feature you want. It's also probably why safety critical code uses other linters and static analyzers.

Comment: The feature I /want/ is the *ability* to use the gcc CLI to trigger the printing of "unused result" in places where the result is unused, especially if I used the `-Wunused-result` flag ...I'll handle the noise